# how to divide money in to different amounts

Tags: c++

I'm trying to do this program for many hours, but I couldn't.

**The question is I've to take some amount of money from user. Then I've to ask how many 5s he have and how many 2s he have. I've to convert that amount of money to 5s and 2s and 1s. User have unlimited source of 1s. In short if user enters 27 I've to tell him 5 5s and 1 2s.**

Now i did this type of program in which I converted time(from seconds to years and so on)

Now I did this in program:-

```
int money;
cout << "How much amount of money= ";
cin >> money;
cout << endl;

int ao5;
cout << "how many number of 5 coins available in your drawer= ";
cin >> ao5;
cout << endl;

int ao2;
cout << "how many number of 2 coins available in your drawer= ";
cin >> ao2;
cout << endl;
int fchange, tchange, ochange;

ochange = (money / 1) % ao5%ao2;
tchange = (money / ao2) % ao5;
fchange = money / ao5;





cout << " " << fchange;
cout << "  " << tchange;
cout << " " << ochange;
```

I've tried other methods. I tried dividing money by 5 and then subtract it with 5s I've but it makes no sense.

Can anyone just take me to right path?

Comment: but if i use float than it wont give me reminder.

Comment: Stop using `float` and use integer.  You will not get exact results using floating point variables.  What currency is this anyway?  U.S. Dollars? If so, do your calculation in pennies, not dollars.  For example, 5 dollars is 500.

Comment: currency is rs and i am using int.

Comment: Do your calculation using the lowest monetary unit.  That is where your first mistake is.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie It's a bit unclear, but I don't think *that* is the OP's problem. Just a limited resources (number of specific coins) problem.

Comment: Sorry about that. I steered the comments in the wrong direction because of a now retracted comment.

Comment: *I've tried other methods. I tried dividing money by 5 and then subtract it with 5s I've but it makes no sense.* -- Why not work this out on paper first, before writing any program?  If you don't know how to do the proper divisions and modulus, then it makes no sense trying to write a program with no knowledge of how to solve the problem.

Comment: le me clear it. The user will give me money amount and the amount of 5s he have and 2s he have.user have unlimited 1s. if he enters he have 3 of 5s and 2 of 2s and value of money is 25, i have to tell him he needs 3 5s 2 2s and 7 1s.

Comment: @MariumSadiq -- ok, so if you had no computer, no program to write, how would you figure out what to give the person?  What steps would you do in "real life" to figure out the problem?   Before writing a program, you have to know what you're writing and whether it solves the problem.  Writing random code hoping the problem is solved isn't the way to do this.

Comment: i will do this. if user enters 30 as money and give me 3 of 5s and 2 of 2s. i will multiply 3x5 and 2x2 and than subtract it from money. and than i will add 1s as coins that are less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this

```
void divid(int num){
if(num>=5){
        int remainderAfterdevidingTo5 = num%5;
        int numOf5s = num/5;
        std::cout << "  numOf5s  "<< numOf5s<< std::endl;
        divid(remainderAfterdevidingTo5);
    }else if(num>=2){
        int remainderAfterdevidingTo2 = num%2;
        int numOf2s = num/2;
        std::cout <<  "  numOf2s  "<< numOf2s<< std::endl;
        divid(remainderAfterdevidingTo2);
    }else if(num>=1){
        std::cout << "  numOf1s  " <<num<< std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: i cant understand this method but Thanks

Comment: You are welcome .. I used recursion for this method .. after dividing the number to 5's I called the method again and passed the remainder after dividing as a **parameter** and so on ..